# Sometimes, I can't drag and drop windows into other workspaces

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, workspaces

Sometimes, I can't drag and drop windows to other workspaces.

It always works when I just boot up my computer. After a while (most often days), it just stops working. I can't drag and drop anymore. I have to close the session and log in again to fix the issue.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 with GNOME Shell 3.30.2, but I remember having this problem with Ubuntu 18.04 too.

Here is a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/s1shbBFvt3o

Update: I just had this issue again with Ubuntu 19.04 and Gnome Shell 3.32.0.

Comment: Can you still move windows between workspaces by right-clicking on the window title bar?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Does closing an opening the session again solve the problem, or only a reboot?

Comment: @wazoox Yes, closing the session fixes the issue. No need for a reboot.

Comment: OK so that's a window manager or desktop manager bug. Very hard to sort out...

Answer (score 2):

Disabling dash to panel fixed it for me in Pop!_OS 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

This is a super late response so I'm not sure if it'll help you, but maybe someone else will stumble across this like I did.

I was experiencing the same bug on a new install of Ubuntu 19.04, what fixed it for me was disabling "Mouse Click Emulation" using the GNOME Tweaks application (which is just a nice front-end for fiddling with GNOME options and extensions, amongst other things). I didn't have to restart my system for the "fix" to work, but you might.

Here's a screenshot of where to find the setting in the Tweaks menu:

[image]

You can definitely do this without having to install the Tweaks app, but I don't know what the exact steps would be.

Comment: Was really hoping this would work for me but no joy unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was in Ubuntu 20.04 with X11 and Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland, and I still don't know how to fix this

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287216)